# Suggestion for an application to do our company car fleet management

Tags: software-recommendation, lamp

(As suggested I've tried asking on webapps with no luck...
So I try on askubuntu: I'll be luckier :) )

Hello, everybody!

Our company could be a little more open source and a little "ubuntier" if I can find an easy and user friendly web application (we already have our LAMP server based on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) to handle company's car fleet expenses and repairs planning.

Any hints? :)

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first port of call should be to investigate various fixed asset management solutions available online for Linux based operating systems:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fams/

You may also find that account management solutions might better encapsulate the problems you want to solve:

http://loll.sourceforge.net/linux/links/Software_Applications/Financial_/index.html

In the end though, don't be scared of picking the closest solution and then searching out for programmers to add in what you need. The unique thing about foss of course is that you can pay others to modify on your behalf.